# Retrieve data from PHP within Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I need to convert country codes into their name from Javascript. I found a php array of country codes but I need to pass a javascript variable into the php array to get the country code. Any way to do something like the following? This errors out of course.

```
function getCountry(code)
        {
            <?php echo $code=?> code;
            return <?php echo $countries[$code] ?>
        }
```

Comment: Output the data structure containing your country codes as JSON, then store it in a variable in JS (the JSON format is native to JS). You can then retrieve values from it as you please.

Comment: Why not just convert that array to a valid javascript object, and use the countrycodes as keys to get the names.

Comment: you can't pass value from javascript to php. it's impossible like this way. you should create an api.

Comment: Whatever you nitwits do, make sure you give a great answer. user1964129 might be the hottest chick on SO and the last thing we need to do is frighten her off.

Comment: @j08691 - +1, I guess I was'nt the only one that noticed that, I just found it a bit inappropriate to comment on it ?

Comment: @adeneo - yeah I'm missing a few filters in my brain. Probably due to the drinking.

Comment: hi, i guess i'll be giving a chick-to-chick answer then (see below) :) - sorry guys to intrude..

Comment: You guys are too funny! Thanks for the help! Let's see if I can implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in javascript:

```
function getCountry(code){
    var countries=<?=json_encode($countries)?>;
    return countries.hasOwnProperty(code)?countries[code]:null;
}
```

I modified it to use a ternary for the error checking, just shorter code.

Comment: @ocanal OP has an array of countries in php and is trying to get that into javascript so they can lookup code in javascript.

Comment: Ok I got it, that should be like this, not in her way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCountry(code)
        {
            var codes = <?php echo json_encode($codes);?> ;
            return (codes[code] || null);
        }
```